# How to append the ouptut of more than a command to a filename through a redirect in bash?

Tags: bash, ubuntu, redirect, scripting

I'm trying to create a file containing the list of packages installed in the system at an exact time. We're trying to compare different hosts at different times to check some sources.list tests so I need the file name to include the hostname and the date.

I know I can use something like:

```
dpkg -l > dpkg-list-`hostname`.txt
```

or

```
dpkg -l > dpkg-list-$(hostname).txt
```

The same with the `date` command. The problem is when I try to combine both variables:

```
    dpkg -l > dpkg-list-$(hostname)$(date).txt
-bash: dpkg-list-$(hostname)$(date).txt: ambiguous redirect
```

I've tried using all combinations of the commands above, bash keeps complaining about an ambiguous redirect.

Now, I know I could easily create a bash script that loads both variables and appends them to the file, but this is more a proof of concept so I'd like to learn how to do this in a one-liner.

Comment: You realise date has spaces in it ? Quote the command sub

Comment: OK, didn't think of that, I thought the problem was in the cat itself :S Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try narrowing the format of `date` output using the following:

```
dpkg -l > dpkg-list-$(hostname)$(date +'%Y%m%d').txt
```

gives:

```
dpkg-list-myhost20160506.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Like @123 commented, use double quotes

```
dpkg -l > "dpkg-list-$(hostname)$(date).txt"
```